# Como puedo implementar Jquery en un proyecto en Meteor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Estoy trabajando con componentes React un ejemplo seria esta plantilla NavBar

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

export default class NavbarLanding extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
        <div className="navbar-landing">
            <nav>
                <div>
                        <ul className="ul-landing">
                                {/* <img src="./public/images/flat-rocket.jpg"></img> */}
                                <li className="navbar-title"><a>Landing </a></li>
                            <div className="navbar-menu">
                                <li><a>acerca</a></li>
                                <li><a>portafolio</a></li>
                                <li><a>contacto</a></li>
                                <button className="btn"onClick={() => Accounts.logout()}>Logout</button>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                </div>
             </nav>
        </div>
        );
    };
}
//export default NavbarLanding;
NavbarLanding.reactProptype = {
    title: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

como puedo integrar jquery con este tipo de plantillas, o tengo que utilizar  para poder inclusionar funciones jquery?

Comment: ¿Importar jQuery y llamar sus funciones no es suficiente para que funcione?

Answer (score 0):

Quiza pueda ayudarte el:

```
import * from 'jquery' as $;
```

Considerando que jQuery lo instalas via NPM.